# How do I create an HTML / CSS code that will allow a scrollable side bar with buttons to change the source of a video in the player beside?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, html5-video

Here’s an example of what I want it to be like:https://tvplayer.com/watch just more simple as in no restrictions. Click to change video source almost like a YouTube playlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - you can't dynamically change page content by **HTML** and **CSS** only. You should use a little bit of **JS**. in our case this one *(check out codepen example to see, how it works)*:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
var source = e.target.dataset.source,
    video = document.getElementById('video');
if (source) {
    video.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + source;
    }
});
```

This is not a perfect code, but good start point for you I guess. Good luck :)

[**Codepen example**](https://codepen.io/faeton/pen/KyegZa)

Comment: Omg thanks this is exactly what I was looking for! One thing though (I’m kind of new to this stuff) is it possible to change the buttons to images?

Comment: Sure, just change tags from button to image, and add src attribute (and not forget about data-source, because without this attribute script will not work). Cheers.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was able to change the buttons to images. I got everything to work perfectly, the only thing that came up as an issue is if I change the source(s) to a direct mp4 file some browsers try to download it. Do you know of any way to fix it? I hope I’m not being too much of a bother

Comment: Nice to know it :) As you can see, the script is written for the youtube videos. You can modify it a little bit, so it will work for your sources.

Comment: You should use <video> tag as video container instead <iframe>. I used iframe just to show the logic. Then as a data-source value you can use your file name (path to the video folder should already filled in src attribute, so js just will add the file name to the src attribute).

Comment: Thanks so much! You’ve been so helpful and I’ve got everything working perfectly now (in the HTML video tag)

Comment: Great. Happy to know, that I was helpful :)